# Update TTL value for existing rows in a table for Cassandra database

Tags: database, cassandra, ttl, nosql

I have Table with lots of records with TTL value set for 1 year while inserting. Now I want to update the records with TTL value to 5 years in simple way. I know we can do it through `UPDATE TABLE USING TTL <value> set column ='' where condition`, but I have million records, so I need a solution with one query.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with one quey.... you can use spark-cassandra connector to read the data and write it back to cassandra...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in a single query. The TTL is written with the data so to change the TTL you have to rewrite everything. I would recommend either a Spark job, A 1 off script to read and rewrite everything, or write a custom compaction tool to rewrite everything during a compaction (easier in 3.x).

Comment: can you recommend the best solution for version 2.1. And also what is Spark job?

Comment: easiest quickest is to just write a little script that reads and rewrites everything with a new ttl. Can use the WRITETIME function on select to get time it was written and use that to derive the new ttl `(5 years - (now - writetime))`